# Arrange data by incremental id value

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I want to rearrange data in an oracle database. The raw data looks as follows:

```
 ID     Delivery Time   Output
------ --------------- --------
 5000   02:00           202
 5005   02:00           205
 5007   02:00           208
 7250   02:00           190
 5001   02:30           645
 5006   02:30           199
 5008   02:30           45
 7251   02:30           99
```

The ID increments and I want to re-arrange such that each output (4 in this instance) each have a specific column and looks as follows:

```
 Delivery Time   Output 1   Output 2    Output 3    Output 4
--------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
 02:00            202         205          208        190
 02:30            645         199           45         99
```

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: So you want to pivot the data? Which version of Oracle are you using? Will there always be (at most) four rows for each delivery time?

Comment: If you have a variable number of outputs per time and just want to use it for reports, then LISTAGG could be good enough.

Comment: What do you want to see if we insert row ('8000', '02:47', 1)? And row: ('5001', '02:30', 7)?